# ember-data: How to make a Saving/Saved flash message

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In order to make a little yellow "Saving"/"Saved" indicator message at the top of my app, I'd like to have a boolean property indicating if any ember-data records are currently in flight.

I tried this:

```
App.store = DS.Store.create
  isSaving: (->
    for record in this.get('recordCache')
      if record?.getPath('stateManager.currentState.name') == 'inFlight'
        return true
    return false
  ).property('recordCache.@each.stateManager.currentState.name')
```

but then I discovered that `recordCache` is not observable.

I don't use transactions, only `App.store.commit()`, so I looked at `App.store.get('defaultTransaction')`, but it didn't yield anything useful.

I'm using the RESTAdapter, so if I can extend it into giving me this piece of information, that would work too.

Comment: Is defaultTransaction.buckets.inflight observable?

Comment: Did you ever figure anything out? I have a solution in place on an app that I'm building, but I don't like it. It extends the DS.Model class and sets the property didUpdate()  to fire a notification whenever a model is saved.

Comment: No, I didn't. Why don't you post your solution as an answer, even if it's a stop-gap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could simply create a base model with a didUpdate property that handles showing your notification message, then have each of your models extend it. It's really a stop-gap solution, but it works for the time being:

```
App.Model = DS.Model.extend
    didUpdate: ->
        # invoke your notification
        alert("All changes saved!")

App.User = App.Model.extend()
```

However....this will fire for EVERY record that is updated. So you'd probably want create your notification class in such a way that it will not open more then one saved notification at once...but that's up to you.

I'm currently working on implementing some of the basic server-validation methods from this pull request https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/376, and I'm hoping that I'll come up with a better way to observe the status of commits (and will of course post back here if I do).

Answer (score 4):

Why not extend model, controller and/or view:

```
DS.Model.reopen({
    didCreate: function() {
        this.set('persisted', true);
    },
    didUpdate: function() {
        this.set('persisted', true);       
    },

    resetPersistenceFlag: function(){
        this.set('persisted', false);
    }.observes('isDirty')

});

Ember.Controller.reopen({
    contentPersistedObserver: function() {
        if (this.get('content.persisted') === true) {
            //do stuff here
        }  
    }.observes('content.persisted')
});

Ember.View.reopen({
    controllerContentPersistedObserver: function() {
        if (this.get('controller.content.persisted') === true) {
            //do stuff here
        }  
    }.observes('controller.content.persisted')
});​
```

That way your controller/view will know when model is saved. It will fire for Create/Update controllers, but for controllers that manage arrays it will not.

Comment: I like this a lot actually, and gets things back into the controller where they belong. Could almost start doing simple error handling too. Still will have the issue where the controller will fire for each record that is updated...so in my case if I have 10 records update at once I get 10 alert windows...but that is outside the scope of this question I think.

Comment: This is a bit wrong, in that didCreate fires immediately, and so does not mean persisted. didUpdate is all you need to set persisted to true.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler solution to this:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({

    init: function () {
        this._super();
        var self = this;
        this.get('controller').content.on('didUpdate', function() {
            self.SomeCoolUpdateFunctionForMyView(self.$());
        });
    }
});
```

self.$() references to the jquery representation of your view.