# How to tell when store.commit() is doing anything in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I've implementing a periodic autosave feature in my Ember app like this:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function () {
        setInterval(function() { App.store.commit(); }, 10000);
    }
});
```

It works great, flushing all changes to the server periodically.  But how I can hook into the event so that I can give a visual indication that it's happening to the user?

I can't just stick it in the 'ready' event handler, because most times App.store.commit() won't actually have any work to do, and even if it did, it happens asynchronously - commit() returns immediately, before the requests are generated.

Comment: perhaps a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726549/ember-data-how-to-make-a-saving-saved-flash-message

Comment: that link was educational, but as they discuss on that page, they haven't come up with a great solution yet

Comment: yep, it does not fully answers to your question :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's true `commit` does not indicated its progress. Setup `didCreate` & `didUpdate` callbacks on your models to inject change notifications into your app.

The nature of the Ember-Data transaction model means that much can happen when a `commit` is requested, or not. Your callback notifications will probably need to be coalesced or throttled into a sensible user-facing message.

**DIY Alternative: create an isSaving property & afterSave observer**

On your controller, use computed properties & observes to watch your specific data model for the `isSaving` state:

```
// Example of a data model with a belongsTo association & nested hasMany
isSaving: function() {
  return this.get('isSaving') || (
    !Ember.empty(this.get('association')) && (
      this.get('association.isSaving') || 
        this.get('association.nestedAssociation').some(function(item) { return item.get('isSaving'); })
    )
  );
}.property("isSaving", "association.isSaving", "association.nestedAssociation.@each.isSaving"),

afterSave: function() {
  if (this.get('isSaving')) return;
  // do something interesting
}.observes('isSaving')
```

This is a dirty compared to a generic, global `isSaving` or `isInFlight` state in ember-data, but it works very well in practice.

Comment: As you say, those callbacks are useful to hook into for change notification, but that's not the goal here. What's missing is a "you've called commit, there are changes, so I'm starting to push them to the server" callback, followed by an "all done" callback... without the before hook, I can't put up a "now saving" indicator, then remove it with the after hook.

Comment: It's possible there's simply no good answer yet, at least not an easy-recipe one.

Comment: The next step is probably to dig into the transaction docs/code. I will as soon as I get the chance, and if I find something useful, I'll post it back here.

Comment: Sounds like you would ideally like to extend/override DS.Store.ajax() to manage an `ajaxRequests` Array property, pushing flags when requests begin, and then popping them as they complete. You could observe that property for size > 0 to reflect in-flight operations in the UI... THE MISSING LINK is that the current DS.Store.ajax() callbacks are not inheritable/overridable.

Comment: That sounds scary relative to my current comfort level with JavaScript and Ember internals. :) I'll just say the answer to my question is "not yet" and mark your answer accepted, especially since it goes into detail.